# API data is not showing in the apk file

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, everything shows up in the emulator. But when I create an APK file, it doesn't show anything at all. I thought this might be a problem regarding network permission. So I added the permissions in all 3 of the Android Manifest files. But its all the same. Is there any solution?

This is my debug AndroidManifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.digitaldisplay">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

This is my main AndroidManifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.digitaldisplay">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label="digitaldisplay"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my profile AndroidManifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.digitaldisplay">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't show anything at all" exactly mean? Do you have access to any error logs?

Comment: Add this permissions to main AndroidManifest file. Maybe helps: ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>```